# How to test Rcpp::CharacterVector elements for equality?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to write some simple Rcpp code examples.  This is remarkably easy with the `Rcpp` and `inline` packages.

But I am stumped on how to test whether two character elements for equality.  The following example compares the first elements of two character vectors.  But I can't get it to compile.

What is the trick?

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

cCode <- '
    Rcpp::CharacterVector cx(x);
    Rcpp::CharacterVector cy(y);
    Rcpp::LogicalVector r(1);
    r[0] = (cx[0] == cy[0]);
    return(r);
    '

cCharCompare <- cxxfunction(signature(x="character", y="character"), 
                            plugin="Rcpp", body=cCode)
cCharCompare("a", "b")
```

--

The comparison using `==` works perfectly fine if one of the two elements is a constant.  The following code compiles and gives expected results:

```
cCode <- '
    Rcpp::CharacterVector cx(x);
    Rcpp::LogicalVector r(1);
    r[0] = (cx[0] == "a");
    return(r);
    '

cCharCompareA <- cxxfunction(signature(x="character"), plugin="Rcpp", body=cCode)

cCharCompareA("a")
[1] TRUE

cCharCompareA("b")
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Where is `test` defined?

Comment: Why do you set things to NULL before setting them with cxxfunction?

Comment: @James Apologies - it should have read `cx[0] == cy[0]` - edited.

Comment: @Spacedman It's just a workflow convenience.  If `cxxfunction` doesn't compile, it doesn't return a value, thus the assigned variable still has its previous value.  It's not necessary for the code to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very nice (technical) answer by @kohske, but here is something more C++-ish: just compare strings!

```
library(inline)      ## implies library(Rcpp) when we use the plugin

cCode <- '
    std::string cx = Rcpp::as<std::string>(x);
    std::string cy = Rcpp::as<std::string>(y);
    bool res = (cx == cy);
    return(Rcpp::wrap(res));
    '

cCharCompare <- cxxfunction(signature(x="character", y="character"),
                            plugin="Rcpp", body=cCode)
cCharCompare("a", "b")
```

If you really want to compare just the first character of the strings, then you can go from `x` to `x.c_str()` and either index its initial element, or just dereference the pointer to the first char.

A more R-ish answer could maybe sweep over actual vectors of strings...

Comment: Thank you for this - it's most helpful.  My real question is of course sweeping over vectors, but in trying to get to the minimal reproducible example, I realised that my problem is with comparing strings, i.e. comparing individual elements of a CharacterVector.  With this bit solved, it should be straight-forward to step up to using the vector operations defined in `Rcpp::Sugar`.

Comment: Before going fancy with *Rcpp sugar* (no :: here as there is no class Sugar), I would try old-school with a loop first.

Answer (score 17):

The equality operator has been introduced in `Rcpp` 0.10.4. The implementation looks like this in the `string_proxy` class:

```
bool operator==( const string_proxy& other){
    return strcmp( begin(), other.begin() ) == 0 ;
}
```

So now we can write:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector test( CharacterVector x, CharacterVector y){
    Rcpp::LogicalVector r(x.size());
    for( int i=0; i<x.size(); i++){
        r[i] = (x[i] == y[i]);
    }
    return(r);
}
```

And something similar is used on our unit tests:

```
> test(letters, letters)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[16] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: This is nice. It will save a bunch of unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
  // r[0] = (cx[0] == cy[0]);
  // r[0] = ((char*)cx[0] == (char*)cy[0]); <- this is wrong
  r[0] = (*(char*)cx[0] == *(char*)cy[0]); // this is correct.
```

It is not easy to explain, but

1. `CharacterVector` is not `char[]`.
2. `operator []` returns `StringProxy`.
3. `StringProxy` is not a type of `char`.
4. `StringProxy` has a member operator function `char*` that convert `StringProxy` to `char*`.

So, maybe `(char*)cx[0]` is a pointer.
Now I forget many things about C++ syntax...

The reason hy the compile fails is the failure of type inference in operator overload `==` for `StringProxy`.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this works.  And thank you for the explanation. (I have tried various forms of coercion to `char`, but the elusive answer was to coerce using `char*`. I suspect there is a bit of `Rcpp` sugar along the lines of `as<char*>(cx[0])` - hopefully somebody can comment and give the correct `Rcpp` sugar syntax.

Comment: @Andrie The first version is incorrect. Current version is correct.