# Rcpp function check if missing value

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm converting R based code into Rcpp based code. The head of my function is:

```
NumericMatrix createMatrixOfLinkRatiosC(NumericMatrix matr, double threshold4Clean) {
int i,j; 
NumericMatrix myMatr(matr.nrow(),matr.ncol());
myMatr=matr;
....;

}
```

I want to handle call to the function where threshold4Clean is missing but I'm not finding how to do... Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say missing, do you mean "NA" or do you mean you aren't passing any value to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both Rcpp and RcppArmadillo have predicates to test for `NA`, `NaN` (an R extension) and `Inf`.

Here is a short RcppArmadillo example:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat foo(int n, double threshold=NA_REAL) {
  arma::mat M = arma::zeros<arma::mat>(n,n);
  if (arma::is_finite(threshold)) M = M + threshold;
  return M;
}

/*** R
foo(2)
foo(2, 3.1415)
***/
```

We initialize a matrix of zeros, and test for the argument. If it is finite (ie not `NA` or `Inf` or `NaN`), then we add that value.  If you wanted to, you could test for the possibilities individually too.

This produces the desired result: without a second argument the default value of `NA` applies, and we get a matrix of zeros.

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/giorgio.cpp")

R> foo(2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

R> foo(2, 3.1415)
       [,1]   [,2]
[1,] 3.1415 3.1415
[2,] 3.1415 3.1415
R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk, do you have also a pure Rcpp example?

Answer (score 33):

R has both `NaN` and `NA` (which is really a special kind of `NaN`) for representing missing values. This is important to know because there are many functions that check if a value is `NaN`-y (`NA` or `NaN`):

Some truth tables for functions from the R/C API (note the frustrating lack of consistency)

```
+---------------------+
| Function | NaN | NA |
+---------------------+
| ISNAN    |  t  | t  |
| R_IsNaN  |  t  | f  |
| ISNA     |  f  | t  |
| R_IsNA   |  f  | t  |
+---------------------+
```

and Rcpp:

```
+-------------------------+
| Function     | NaN | NA |
+-------------------------+
| Rcpp::is_na  |  t  | t  |
| Rcpp::is_nan |  t  | f  |
+-------------------------+
```

and from the R interpreter (note: Rcpp tries to match this, rather than the R/C API):

```
+---------------------+
| Function | NaN | NA |
+---------------------+
| is.na    |  t  | t  |
| is.nan   |  t  | f  |
+---------------------+
```

Unfortunately it's a confusing landscape, but this should empower you a bit.

Comment: Nicely done.  Maybe we should pull this over into the Rcpp FAQ as well?

Answer (score 5):

I've been testing this and can shed some light on the possibilities.

For a single `SEXP target`, the `Rcpp` option I've used is:

```
switch(TYPEOF(target)) {
case INTSXP:
    return Rcpp::traits::is_na<INTSXP>(Rcpp::as<int>(target));
case REALSXP:
    return Rcpp::traits::is_na<REALSXP>(Rcpp::as<double>(target));
case LGLSXP:
    return Rcpp::traits::is_na<LGLSXP>(Rcpp::as<int>(target));
case CPLXSXP:
    return Rcpp::traits::is_na<CPLXSXP>(Rcpp::as<Rcomplex>(target));
case STRSXP: {
    Rcpp::StringVector vec(target);
    return Rcpp::traits::is_na<STRSXP>(vec[0]);
}
}
```

If you want to check without using `Rcpp` there are some caveats:

- As mentioned [here](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/240_na_nan_inf.html),
  integer and logical `NA` (both stored as `int`) is equal to the minimum value of `int` (-2147483648).
- For `double`, you could directly use what [`Rcpp` uses](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/traits/is_na.h),
  namely `R_isnancpp`.
  Equivalently, the [`ISNAN` macro](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/R_ext/Arith.h#L72) could be used.
- For complex numbers, you could check both real and imaginary parts with the `double` method from above.

Character `NA` is tricky, since it's a singleton, so the address is what matters.
I personally have been testing ways to do operations with R characters without storing `std::string` to avoid copies,
i.e. using the `char*` directly.
What I've found that works is to declare this in a `.cpp` file:

```
static const char *na_string_ptr = CHAR(Rf_asChar(NA_STRING));
```

and, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875438/5793905),
do something like this for a `Rcpp::StringVector` or `Rcpp::StringMatrix` `x`:

```
Rcpp::CharacterVector one_string = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::CharacterVector>(x[i]);
char *ptr = (char *)(one_string[0]);
return ptr == na_string_ptr;
```

This last one still uses `Rcpp`,
but I can use it once for initial setup and then just use the `char` pointers.
I'm sure there's a way to do something similar with R's API,
but that's something I haven't tried yet.