# How is noNA used in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

In his "Advanced R" book, Hadley Wickham says "`noNA(x)` asserts that the vector `x` does not contain any missing values." However I still don't know how to use it. I can't do

```
if (noNA(x))
    do this
```

so how am I supposed to use it?

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-sugar

Comment: Please provide the exact reference, i.e., a link.

Comment: There's an example on page 14 of [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf)

Comment: This is essentially a) a FAQ (with the canonical answer [here in  this *epic* post by Kevin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241085/rcpp-function-check-if-missing-value/26262984#26262984) and b) your own making if you trust secondary documentation over primary.

Comment: I couldn't understand the primary documentation. Hadley's book was the closest I got to something I could understand. Kevin's answer is informative, indeed I have seen it before, however I did not learn from it how `noNA` is used.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel To be fair, the first Google hit that looks like a documentation [is, in fact, completely undocumented](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/namespaceRcpp.html#ac6caefefde6b53b704f65b0716d35c20). In fact, I’m not sure which documentation you’re referring to here.

Comment: @Konrad: Contributions are welcome on documentation too.  But you can search in the same doxygen tree, or [directly on GitHub](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=noNA) and that *does* give usage examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the Rcpp sugar expressions are implemented through template classes which have specializations for cases when the input object is *known* to be free of missing values, thereby allowing the underlying algorithm to avoid having to perform the extra work of dealing with `NA` values (e.g. calls to `is_na`). This is only possible because the [`VectorBase`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/81c40d7df9bff638a02df7eb085226f0e9317933/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/VectorBase.h#L28) class has a boolean parameter indicating whether the underlying object *can* (can, not that it necessarily *does*) have `NA` values, or not.

[`noNA`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/nona/nona.h#L73-L76) returns (when called on a `VectorBase` object) an instance of the [`Nona`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/nona/nona.h#L28-L59) template class. Note that `Nona` itself derives from

```
Rcpp::VectorBase<RTYPE, false, Nona<RTYPE,NA,VECTOR>>
//                      ^^^^^
```

meaning that the returned object gets encoded with information that essentially says "you can assume that this data is free of `NA` values".

As an example, `Rcpp::sum` is implemented via the `Sum` class in the `Rcpp::sugar` namespace. In the [default case](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/81c40d7df9bff638a02df7eb085226f0e9317933/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sum.h#L28-L51), we see that there is extra work to manage the possibility of missing values:

```
STORAGE get() const {
    STORAGE result = 0 ;
    R_xlen_t n = object.size() ;
    STORAGE current ;
    for( R_xlen_t i=0; i<n; i++){
        current = object[i] ;
        if( Rcpp::traits::is_na<RTYPE>(current) )   // here
            return Rcpp::traits::get_na<RTYPE>() ;  // here
        result += current ;
    }
    return result ;
}
```

On the other hand, there is also [a specialization](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/81c40d7df9bff638a02df7eb085226f0e9317933/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sum.h#L74-L93) for cases when the input does not have missing values, in which the algorithm does less work:

```
STORAGE get() const {
    STORAGE result = 0 ;
    R_xlen_t n = object.size() ;
    for( R_xlen_t i=0; i<n; i++){
        result += object[i] ;
    }
    return result ;
}
```

---

To answer your question of "how do I apply this in practice?", here is an example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int Sum(IntegerVector x) {
    return sum(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int SumNoNA(IntegerVector x) {
    return sum(noNA(x));
}
```

---

Benchmarking these two functions,

```
set.seed(123)
x <- as.integer(rpois(1e6, 25))

all.equal(Sum(x), SumNoNA(x))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    Sum(x), 
    SumNoNA(x),
    times = 500L
)
# Unit: microseconds
#        expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#      Sum(x) 577.386 664.620 701.2422 677.1640 731.7090 1214.447   500
#  SumNoNA(x) 454.990 517.709 556.5783 535.1935 582.7065 1138.426   500
```

the `noNA` version is indeed faster.