# Checking Null and NA of a vector in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to evaluate the sum of a vector (`y`) conditional on whether the values of a second nullable vector (`r`) is `NA` or not. If the second vector `r` is NULL, all of the values of `y` should be summed. If all elements of `r` is `NA`, function should return NA. Please see the end of the text for the desired output.

I tried the following code first:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('double foo(NumericVector y, Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::IntegerVector> r = R_NilValue) {
  double output = 0;
  bool return_na = !Rf_isNull(r);
  int y_count = y.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < y_count; i++) {
    if (Rf_isNull(r)  || !R_IsNA(r[i])) {
    //// if (Rf_isNull(r)  || !R_IsNA(as<IntegerVector>(r)[i])) {
      if (!Rf_isNull(r))
        Rcout << R_IsNA(as<IntegerVector>(r)[i]) << " - "<< as<IntegerVector>(r)[i] << std::endl;
      output = output + y[i];
      return_na = false;
    } 
  }
  if (return_na) 
    return NA_REAL;
  return output;
}')
```

This gave me the following error:

```
 error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct SEXPREC'
     if (Rf_isNull(r)  || !R_IsNA(r[i])) {
                                     ^
```

In order to solve it, I used `if (Rf_isNull(r)  || !R_IsNA(as<IntegerVector>(r)[i])) {` instead. But this time, when converting to an integer vector, `NA` values are converted to a number and `R_IsNA()` test gives a false positive.

Here is the expected output that I want.

```
foo(1:4, NULL) #  <- This should return 10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
foo(1:4, c(1, 1, 1, 1)) #  <- This should return 10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
foo(1:4, c(1, 1, NA, 1)) #  <- This should return 7 = 1 + 2 + 4
foo(1:4, c(NA, NA, NA, NA)) # <- This should return NA
```

How can I get the function that I want? (This example is simplified, I'm not particularly interested in sum function. Instead, I'm interested in checking `NA` and `NULL` simultaneously as given in the example.)

Comment: Are you aware of this classic answer by Kevin?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241085/rcpp-function-check-if-missing-value/26262984#26262984

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that post. I reviewed Kevin's answer before. But in this case I cannot find it's use for my particular case. The next post (from Alexis) was more helpful in my case. Previously, instead of  `!R_IsNA(as<IntegerVector>(r)[i])`, I tried `!is_na(r[i])` or `!is_na(as<IntegerVector>(r)[i])` but both raised errors. But when I specify the type of `NA`, like this `!IntegerVector::is_na(as<IntegerVector>(r)[i])`, it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three suggestions:

- Use Rcpp instead of R's C API.
- Return early when `r` is `NULL`.
- Create a `LogicalVector` before looping through the input vector.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo(Rcpp::NumericVector y, Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::IntegerVector> r = R_NilValue) {
    if (r.isNull())
        return Rcpp::sum(y);

    Rcpp::LogicalVector mask = Rcpp::is_na(r.as());
    if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::all(mask))) 
        return NA_REAL;

    double output = 0.0;
    int y_count = y.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < y_count; ++i) {
        if (!mask[i]) {
            output += y[i];
        } 
    }
    return output;
}

/***R
foo(1:4, NULL) #  <- This should return 10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
foo(1:4, c(1, 1, 1, 1)) #  <- This should return 10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
foo(1:4, c(1, 1, NA, 1)) #  <- This should return 7 = 1 + 2 + 4
foo(1:4, c(NA, NA, NA, NA)) # <- This should return NA
*/
```

Result:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('60569482.cpp')

> foo(1:4, NULL) #  <- This should return 10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
[1] 10

> foo(1:4, c(1, 1, 1, 1)) #  <- This should return 10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
[1] 10

> foo(1:4, c(1, 1, NA, 1)) #  <- This should return 7 = 1 + 2 + 4
[1] 7

> foo(1:4, c(NA, NA, NA, NA)) # <- This should return NA
[1] NA
```

Further suggestion:

- Use the mask for sub-setting `y`.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo(Rcpp::NumericVector y, Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::IntegerVector> r = R_NilValue) {
    if (r.isNull())
        return Rcpp::sum(y);

    Rcpp::LogicalVector mask = Rcpp::is_na(r.as());
    if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::all(mask))) 
        return NA_REAL;

    Rcpp::NumericVector tmp = y[!mask];
    return Rcpp::sum(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a mask, you can use `if(y[i] != NA_INTEGER)` in the loop, and keep track if any elements are not NA with another variable.  That should be overall more efficient.

Comment: @thc Alternatively one could use `!Rcpp::is_na(y[i])`. I find the last version easier to reason about, which **can** be more important than the last bit of performance. We don't know if it is the case here ...